# Unable to download files from cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, browser, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am facing an issue with trying to download a file from the server in the cordova android app...In the cordova app we are using the inappbrowser to open a web application in html and JS. When we try to do window.open("url","_blank") we are unable to get the file to be downloaded.

From the server we are getting 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"

Still i am unable to get the files to get downloaded 
Response headers have the content disposition set and the response seems to be empty with a content type text/file

One concern for us is that the cookies need to be sent alongside with the request and is set by the server after authentication, hence we cannot use the external browser (using _system)

Thanks

Comment: Have you whitelisted the URL in your cross domain policy? Also, where are you trying to download the files to?

Comment: Hey thanks andrew.. Yep the URL's are whitelisted for the domain of the server and its paths... I have been trying to download the files from the browser just like any other download.. like it defaults to where the browser downloads the files

Comment: However still m not able to get it to download files